# Parse lib sends signup request multiple times

Tags: android, parse-platform

If a user is registered by calling the following call once:

```
   private void signup() {
        ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
        user.setUsername("ola");
        user.setPassword("kari4ever");
        user.setEmail("ola@nordmann.no");

        user.put("phone", "650-253-0000");

        user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    toast("Hooray! The user is signed up");
                } else {
                    toast("signup failed \n" + e.toString());
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

If the user already exists, the parse library repeats the HTTP request many times before the `SingupCallback.done()` method is called.

[image: as seen in this screenshot]

Is this a bug?

Comment: There is no bug.. show me how you're calling `signup()`.

Comment: Tested using a test case and an app. I can't paste code here. Would you like me to push up to github?

Comment: Parse doesn't store duplicate entries. Are you sure the Email ID's stored at parse.com are same for all the entries?

Comment: Yes one call to `signup()` results in many network calls if the user already exists.

Comment: There is no issue related to Parse whatsoever. I would recommend debugging using breakpoints.

Comment: @Tushar do you work at Parse? How do you know there is no issue. I have debugged with breakpoints: One call to `signup()` 5 or 6 calls over the wire.